# if $4^{\alpha} \equiv k+1 \pmod{2k+1}$ prove there is no $\beta$ where $4^{\beta} \equiv k\pmod{2k+1}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $3 \nmid 2k+1$ and there is $\alpha$ with $4^{\alpha} \equiv k+1 \pmod{2k+1}$ where $0 \leq \alpha \leq k$. I want to prove that there is no $\beta$, $0\leq \beta \leq k$ such that $4^{\beta} \equiv k \pmod{2k+1}$. I have used the contradiction method but there was no result, it will be nice if you help me about it with your ideas, thanks.

Comment: What does a congruence $4^\alpha \equiv k+1 \pmod{2k+1}$ imply about the order of $2$ modulo $2k+1$?

Comment: sorry ,I didn't understand your question , but with some calculation we have $2^{2\alpha +1} \equiv 1 (mod 2k+1)$,

Comment: Good. So the order of $2$ divides $2\alpha + 1$, and that means ...

Comment: sorry but I really couldn't complete your statement.

Comment: Let $m = \min \{ n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\} : 2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{2k+1}\}$. Then $m \mid 2\alpha +1$. What does that tell you about $m$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer,from $4^{\alpha} \equiv 4^{\beta}$ and $(4,2k+1)=1$ we have $2^{2(\alpha -\beta)} \equiv 1$ and so $ 2(\alpha -\beta) \mid 2k+1$ then $2 \mid 2k+1$ which is a contradiction! was it right?

Comment: $m$ can't be even!

Comment: Close, but we don't have $4^\alpha \equiv 4^\beta \pmod{2k+1}$, rather $4^\alpha \equiv -4^\beta\pmod{2k+1}$.

Comment: yes,your right and then we have $2^{2(\alpha -\beta)-1} \equiv k$ and what is next?

Comment: What you had before was closer, look at $2^{2\lvert\alpha-\beta\rvert} \equiv -1\pmod{2k+1}$.

Comment: I don't know! a little help please!how I can relate it to $2^{2\alpha+1} \equiv 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m$ be the order of $2$ modulo $2k+1$, $m = \min \bigl\{ n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\} : 2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{2k+1}\bigr\}$.

If $2^{2\alpha} = 4^\alpha \equiv k+1 \pmod{2k+1}$, then $2^{2\alpha+1} \equiv 1 \pmod{2k+1}$, so $m\mid (2\alpha + 1)$, hence $m$ is odd.

If on the other hand $2^{2\beta} = 4^\beta \equiv k \pmod{2k+1}$, then $2^{2\beta + 1} \equiv -1 \pmod{2k+1}$ and $2^{2(2\beta+1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{2k+1}$. So then $m \mid 2(2\beta+1)$ but $m\nmid (2\beta+1)$, and that implies $2\mid m$, i.e. $m$ is even.

Thus at most one of the congruences $4^\alpha \equiv k+1 \pmod{2k+1}$ and $4^\beta \equiv k \pmod{2k+1}$ can be solvable for any $k$.

Comment: I didn't do the same calculation for $\beta$!it is a  great proof! I have learned a lot! thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $4^{\alpha} \equiv k+1 \pmod{2k+1}$, therefore $4^{2\alpha} \equiv k^2 \pmod{2k+1}$. Should such a $\beta$ exist, then $4^{2\beta} \equiv k^2 \pmod{2k+1}$. Thus $4^{2\alpha} \equiv 4^{2\beta} \pmod{2k+1}$. Can you go from here?

Comment: I supposed there is a $\beta$ and I achieved something like yours,$4^{\alpha} \equiv 4^{\beta} (mod \: 2k+1)$ but can't go further,can you explain a little more after this?thanks.

Comment: So $4^{2\lvert \alpha-\beta\rvert} \equiv 1 \pmod{2k+1}$. But I too don't see where to go from there. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: can we conclude here that $4|\alpha -\beta| \mid 2\alpha +1$ then $2 \mid 2\alpha +1$ where is a contradiction?